# How to access attributes of inner tags in custom controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control for building forms to automatically generate a label-input field pair. But I need to be able to modify attributes of the generated label-input field pair in my vb code behind file. The problem is that the code behind file seems to be applied before the custom control. How do I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expose the inner controls as public properties of your custom control.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomControl : CustomControl
{
    Label _label;

    // initialize _label in OnInit() ...

    public string LabelText { get { return _label.Text; } set { _label.Text = value; } }
}
```

Comment: So how would I get something like inputfield.Value?